# How to show image while url is loading

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I am working on a WebView app. I can open my link on WebView but i want to show a loading image while url is loading. How to show a loading image while url is loading?

Comment: You can show a loading indicator **WHILE** the page loads not the elements in it, specifically

Comment: what do you have so far? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve it in 2 different ways

1. Inject JS code which will check `document.ready` state and show an image while not
2. Add `UIImageVIew` as subview then

set `isHidden` property of the subview as false in `WKNavigationDelegate` method

`func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)`

and as true in

`func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)`